# Работа с цифрами числа

Tags: c#

Задача:

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num
> and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of
> times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single
> digit. Example:
>
> 39 → 3 (because 3 * 9 = 27, 2 * 7  = 14, 1*4 = 4 and 4 has only one digit)

Моя идея такова: до тех пор, пока произведение цифр числа больше или равно 10 мы дробим число на цифры, записывая их в `List<T>`; затем перемножаем цифры, сохраняя результат в переменную, и, если он меньше 10, - выходим из цикла.

Мой код который работает только с `int` параметром `number`, а должен работать с `long` и я не знаю как это сделать:

```
private static int Persistence(long number)
{
    int numberOfSteps = 0;
        List<int> digits = new List<int>();

        while (number >= 10)
        {
            int product = 1;
            while (number > 0)
            {
                digits.Add((int)(number % 10));
                number /= 10;
            }
            foreach (var num in digits)
            {
                product *= num;
            }
            number = product;
            numberOfSteps++;
            digits = new List<int>();
        }
        return numberOfSteps;
}
```

Comment: ... не пробовали поменять int на long?

Comment: `long number`, `long product` (и может быть `long numberOfSteps`)

Comment: @iiKuzmychov попробовал в строке где со списком работаю, работать стало, но теперь выдаёт ошибку что на один шаг больше возвращает чем должно

Comment: вот `List<int> digits` вам менять на `List<long>` как раз нет смысла, у вас там элементы в пределах от 0 до 10. Поменяйте как я написал в предыдущем комментарии

Comment: @iiKuzmychov digits.Add(number % 10); в этой строке привожу number к int  и работает, теперь проблема в том что возвращает на один шаг больше чем должно

Comment: обновите код в своём вопросе и добавьте пример входных-выходных данных на которых он работает некорректно

Comment: на числе 39 выдаёт 4 когда должно быть три шага, код обновил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144380/discussion-between-mark-and-iikuzmychov).

Comment: `return numberOfSteps - 1;`? или `int numberOfSteps = -1;`

Comment: @aepot выдаёт -1 шаг когда должно быть 0, так что тоже не подходит

Comment: цифры постоянно складываются в список и не удаляются

Comment: тут вы, кстати, `digits.Add((int)number % 10);` неправильно привели, у вас так большие числа обрежутся, правильно так: `digits.Add((int)(number % 10));`

Comment: получается, [9, 3] -> [9, 3, 7, 2]  и т.д, пока не встретится 0 и произведение не обнулится,

Comment: Спасибо за замечание по поводу списка и приведения числа к инту. Сейчас обновлю свой код

Comment: @siarhei987 подскажите пожалуйста, как мне указать все подсказки как ответ?

Comment: @Mark я не знаю

Answer (score -1):

Вот код решающий поставленную задачу:

```
private static int Persistence(long number)
{
    int numberOfSteps = 0;
        List<int> digits = new List<int>();

        while (number >= 10)
        {
            int product = 1;
            while (number > 0)
            {
                digits.Add((int)(number % 10));
                number /= 10;
            }
            foreach (var num in digits)
            {
                product *= num;
            }
            number = product;
            numberOfSteps++;
            digits = new List<int>();
        }
        return numberOfSteps;
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).